# Php postgresql variables in a query

Tags: php, postgresql, pg-query

I'm trying to get the right syntax for the following. In this case $post_pub = 1

```
$sql='SELECT "Publications"."Pub_ID", "Publications"."ART_TITEL" FROM "Publications" where "Pub_ID"="$post_pub"';
```

Php throws an error: column "$post_pub" does not exist

I've stumbled across pg_query_params, this feels like the right direction, but I need some help. How can I get this to work?

Comment: remove double quotes arounf variable

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**pgsql**](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: ok, so trying to get my head around this http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used `pg_connect` though I think you need something like this:

```
$sql='SELECT "Publications"."Pub_ID", "Publications"."ART_TITEL" 
FROM "Publications" 
where "Pub_ID"=$1 ';


$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $sql, array($post_pub));
```

Comment: Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1: ...ns"."ART_TITEL" FROM "Publications" where "Pub_ID"=$post_pub ^ in ...

Comment: var dump shows the query: string(103) "SELECT "Publications"."Pub_ID", "Publications"."ART_TITEL" FROM "Publications" where "Pub_ID"=$post_pub"

Comment: Ok, solved, I did change $Pub_ID to $1, I assume you can't repeat variables here.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is double quotes around variable. Postgres understands it as "database object" name, in this part of query, a column. to avoid it, try using:

```
$sql='SELECT "Publications"."Pub_ID", "Publications"."ART_TITEL" FROM "Publications" where "Pub_ID"='."$post_pub";
```

also consider moving to PDO - such usage is a straight invitation for sql injection. Setting`$post_pub` to `0 or (delete from Publications)"` will delete all data if user has enough right, for example.

Comment: after changing this error: Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1: ...ns"."ART_TITEL" FROM "Publications" where "Pub_ID"=$post_pub ^ in ...

Comment: Do I need to use pg_prepare and pg_execute? I'm a noob to postgresql after using mysql for a number of years.

Comment: @GaryNobles yes

Comment: Thank you for editing the code, I'm using pg_connect not PDO, the code isn't working, throws a http 500 error.

Comment: the @Oto's advice is preferable - use `pg_query_params`